# Get Time till Christmas using Joda Time

Tags: java, datetime, date, jodatime, duration

I need to calculate the time till Christmas in milliseconds. I'm using joda time and I tried using `Period`, but after wasting a lot of time on Google, I realized that this is wrong, and I could calculate milliseconds. However, my implementation is incorrect and I'm getting wrong results.

My code:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(DateTime.now());
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0 ,0);
org.joda.time.Duration duration = new Period(end, start).toDurationFrom(new Instant());
int millis = (int) DateTimeUtils.getDurationMillis(duration);
Log.d("Millis", String.valueOf(millis));
```

I tried looking at the Joda Time Documentation, but I could not find an answer.

Comment: You should change your millis value to a long, I'm not sure an int will be as acurate as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just calculate milliseconds, it's easy - no need to go via a `Period` at all.

```
long milliseconds = end.getMillis() - start.getMillis();
```

(It's not clear why you're calling `new DateTime(DateTime.now())` by the way - just `DateTime.now()` will suffice.)

EDIT: It works fine for me:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime start = DateTime.now();
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(end.getMillis() - start.getMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I get negative value. Why is that?

Comment: @Isuru: No idea. You used my exact code? I can't test it right now.

Comment: Well it should be long milliseconds =  - start.getMillis() - end.getMillis(); When I change like this, I get an positive value. Am I right or missing something?

Comment: @IsuruMadusanka: No, it should *definitely* be `end.getMillis() - start.getMillis()` - after all, `end` is later than `start`, so should have a larger `millis` value.

Comment: @IsuruMadusanka: I've edited my answer to include a short but complete program demonstrating how you can do this - and it gives me a positive number. I suggest you compare that to your code.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.**

So, this answer is for anyone looking for a solution using [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

### Solution using java.time API

```
ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(Instant.now(), OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2023, 12, 25), LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())
```

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents instantaneous point on the timeline.

Alternatively, you can use `OffsetDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` as follows:

```
ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC), OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2023, 12, 25), LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC))
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/VjWmp3)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

`int` being 32 bits long can store values anywhere between `-2147483648` and `2147483647` if its signed which it is by default, `unsigned` its between 0 and `4294967295`, once such values are exceed it, an overflow, occurs and the values are wrapped around, as such `2147483647 + 1 == -2147483648`, in your case if you tried to set a larger value, type `long` is 64 bits as such it `can` hold larger values and it probably does in this case, to an int, same thing occurs, which is why you may be getting the wrong values.

`DateTimeUtils.getDurationMillis` returns a `long`